# How do Iterators act when working with databases?

Tags: sql, database, iterator

Making queries like `SELECT * FROM people` could create serious memory problems, i.e., as many like to call it, "memory exceeded".

Many programmers invoke using **iterators** to reduce memory consumption. Iterators are a sort of "play-n-pause video recording", meaning that they procuce a value, they stop, they produce a value and so on, avoiding to generate all the values all at once. An example in Python could be the following:

```
def myIterator():
  for i in range(10):
    yield i * 2
```

Now, when it comes to use iterators to fetch data from databases, I get pretty confused. I was always told to limit the number of queries toward a database because it could become a bottleneck and, using iterators, it seems to me to increment the number of queries. Is it so? How does an iterator work with database queries? Is this the well-known problem of the short bed sheet, again? In addition, what happens if, during the fetch phase with an iterators, some data is added in the database?

P.S. My question isn't related to a particular programming language, but it is in general.

Comment: what do you think is the difference between getting the top 10 against the top 10,000 over 100 users?

Comment: Well, it depends. If you make a single query using only the LIMIT feature no one. But if you fetch 1 row at time then the difference is that in the first case you will make 10 queries, in the second 10000 and in the third 100.

Answer (score 0):

RDBMS comes to help when using iterators. DB client sends a request, to which DB replies with the first batch of rows; once the client acknowledges the receipt, the server stops sending, and waits.

DB client library lets the program that uses iterators "digest" the data, until the program iterates past what's already buffered. At that point it asks RDBMS to continue sending the data.

It is up to the program to decide what to do with the data. If it does not store the whole thing in memory, it uses up only as much data as is buffered by DB client.

Comment: So, in this way will the DB be busier? Will it be more involved? Do the bottleneck probabilities increase?

Comment: @antox RDBMS does need to store the position for each active read, along with some additional info, so in this sense DB does get busier. On the other hand, once RDBMS has sent DB client the next batch of data, it does not use additional CPU for your request until you ask for more data. With lots of clients doing it at the same time, RDBMS has a good chance of becoming a bottleneck, but usually the slowest part is disk I/O, not CPU.

Comment: So using iterators is, more or less, like doing (in MySQL) the following query `SELECT * FROM people LIMIT offset, 1` adding at every turn 1 to the offset value. Is it so?

Comment: @antox Not at all! A lot more than one row can be buffered by DB client, depending on how big is the row, and how you configure the client library. If the row is very wide, DB would buffer a hundred or so; if the row is narrow, say, one or two columns, DB would buffer a few thousand, depending on the size of fetch buffer.